# Save sqlite query result in excel with perl

Tags: perl, excel, sqlite

I have the following perl code to execute the sqlite query and save the result in a text file. But I want to save the result in an excel table. Is there any way I can do that?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;
my $dbfile = 'C:\usage.db3';      # your database file
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          # connect to your database, create if needed
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile", # DSN: dbi, driver, database file
    "",                          # no user
    "",                          # no password
    { RaiseError => 1 },         # complain if something goes wrong
) or die $DBI::errstr;

#use Data::Dump::Streamer;


my $array1 = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT  USR.id,USR.name, ST.license FROM users USR, status ST, upd_ate UD WHERE UD.upt_id = (select max(p2.upt_id) from upd_ate p2) AND ST.id = USR.id AND ST.upt_id = UD.upt_id ORDER BY ST.license,USR.name");



open FILE, ">btc.txt" or die $!;


foreach my $Ilink (@$array1) {
my ($id, $name, $license) = @$Ilink;
print FILE "$id|$name|$license\n";
}
close FILE;
```

Thanks

Comment: try `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`

Comment: you can also just open btc.txt in Excel directly, if that is all you need to do, just have it in an Excel file

Comment: @ J-16 SDiZ: I tried that but I have this error: cannot locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm

Comment: @ Scott I tried that but it'll just put everthing in one column, while I want it to be in a table

Comment: @shaleen: you coult try writing it out to an HTML file (containing a table), and open that in Excel. That even allows you to merge cells, and apply styling to your table.

Comment: @shaleen, once you open in XL, use Data->Text-to-Columns on the menu bar / ribbon to get columns for table like data. After that you can save in XLS(x) format if you like. Also, for Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, you need to download and install the module from CPAN.

Comment: I got it done using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel; just had to download Spreadsheet...thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Excel::Template](https://metacpan.org/module/Excel%3a%3aTemplate) module for the somewhat similar goals: in our project we had to create several hundreds (or even thousands) of spreadsheets in .xls format. These spreadsheets had the same layout, but, of course, very different data inside. )

I liked the general idea of this module: you create a template file (let's call it `license.xml`) like this:

```
<workbook>
  <worksheet name="licenses">
    <loop name="license_data">
      <row>
        <cell text="$id"></cell>
        <cell text="$name"></cell>
        <cell text="$license"></cell>
      </row>
    </loop> 
  </worksheet>
</workbook>
```

... then pass some data into it, like this:

```
use strict;
use Excel::Template;

my $template = Excel::Template->new(
    filename => 'license.xml',
);

$template->param('license_data' => [
  { id => 1, name => 'John Doe', license => '77-77-7' },
  { id => 2, name => 'Jack Right', license => '88-88-8' }
]);

$template->write_file('license.xls');
```

... and voila! You have a complete XLS-file at the end of this script's work. )

**UPDATE:** It was so long ago that I completely messed up the template's syntax in the first revision of this post. :( Now it works ok, I've checked. )

Besides, I'd also like to mention that Excel::Template abilities are somewhat limited (it's a really complicated process to insert a merged cell, for example). I've read that [Excel::Template::Plus](https://metacpan.org/module/Excel%3a%3aTemplate%3a%3aPlus) is somewhat more capable, but yet to find a real task to practice it on. )

Answer (score 0):

I do it with [DBI_to_Excel.pm](https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/DBI_to_Excel.pm) and [from_dbi_to_excel.pl](https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/from_dbi_to_excel.pl) using [fbs_load.yml](https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/fbs_load.yml)